# Is this a valid REST API?

Tags: api, rest, url

I am designing an API.

There's the user profile, accessible at

http://example.org/api/v1/users (resp. [http://example.org/api/v1/users/:id](http://example.org/api/v1/users/%3aid))

Now, the user's profile will be dynamic.
So we will allow an API function to add a new profile attribute.

Is the following a valid REST API URL for this?

POST http://example.org/api/v1/users/attributes

Indeed, to retrieve a specific user, the user's id would be appended to the `.../users/` URL.
Now if I use the "`attributes`" element after `/users/`, would that somehow break the user id pattern for the URL?

I'd like to keep the base URL to be `api/v1/users` though, because logically I am modifying the users profile still...

EDIT: The attributes would be added valid for all profiles, it's independent of a user. Say the profile has "name", "surname", "email", and I want to add "address" to all profiles (Of course I know that users with a missing "address" field would not get the new attribute)

What is a good practice to address such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the id should be kept in the URL because you are adding the attributes to a specific user, right?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. No, the attributes would be added valid for all profiles, it's independent of a user. Say the profile has "name", "surname", "email", and I want to add "address" to all profiles (Of course I know that users with a missing "address" field would not get the new attribute). Will add this to the question.

Comment: In that case your URL looks like a valid API structure to me :)

Answer (score 1):

It is an acceptable solution to use the `/api/v1/users/attributes` as long as the `:id` cannot be the text: "attributes". However I recommend to create your own media type, microformat, or microdata for the attributes, because it is rather a type than a resource.

I think you should check these links:

- http://alps.io/spec/index.html
- http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/spec/latest/core/
- http://schema.org/
- http://microformats.org/wiki/microformats2
- http://amundsen.com/media-types/maze/

If the user can set what attributes she can have, only then should you use a resource for attributes. But then each user should have one. But I don't think using resources will be necessary, microdata and microformats both contain more than enough person description attributes...

**Some update after 5 months:**

> Now if I use the "attributes" element after /users/, would that
>   somehow break the user id pattern for the URL?

From the perspective of the client that "id pattern" does not exist. The client follows links by checking the semantics annotated to them. So REST clients are completely decoupled from the URI structure of the actual REST API (aka. [uniform interface constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)). If your pattern breaks, then it is completely a server side, link generation and routing issue, which is not a client side concern.

> Say the profile has "name", "surname", "email", and I want to add
>   "address" to all profiles. What is a good practice to address such an
>   issue?

Address is an optional field in this case and probably a sub-resource, because it can have further fields, like city, postal code, street, etc... You can add address separately, for example with `PUT /users/123/address {city: "", street: "", ...}` or you can add those fields to your user form, and add a partial update to the user, like `PATCH /users/123 {address: {city: "", street: "", ...}}` if only the address changes.

Comment: Yours is a very sensible response. Indeed I started questioning the validity of the requirement. Adding the field, what is its semantics? I can't add any information to any profile in fact, this needs to be done individually for every profile! So what I am thinking is: use the `PUT /collection/` verb, which is normally not used for REST, to signal to the API that there's a new attribute; so it can include it in the "template" for future responses in the `GET /collection/` call (we're using hypermedia); then it's up to the app to update profiles individually

Comment: and it can't be a resource, because I don't want to allow deleting profile attributes through an API call - maybe some other application is already relying on this attribute...

Comment: Why do you need that collection anyways? Just simply `PUT /users/:id` and send `{newattr: value}` is enough. By a simple GET request you can list all of the attributes... Are you sure you really need a catalog of the attributes?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to update every resource in the entire collection I would send a `PATCH` request to `/users`.

Answer (score 0):

While it is a valid URI, I would suggest avoiding `POST http://example.org/api/v1/users/attributes`. In my opinion, it violates the principle of least surprise when a collection endpoint has a child node which is not a member of the collection. If you want to track user attributes as shared by all users, then that's a separate collection, perhaps `/user-attributes`.

```
POST /user-attributes
{
    "name": "Email Address",
    "type": "String",
    ...
}
```

`GET /user-attributes` would return all the possible attributes, and `GET /user-attributes/{id}` would return all the metadata around an attribute.

If there's no metadata, then @inf3rno's suggestion to just PUT the attribute up and let the server deal with it is definitely worth considering.

This all presupposes you need to manage attributes through the API. If not, I agree with @inf3rno that media types are the way to go. Of course, in that case you may want a media type for the user-attributes resource ..